# Python - Avoiding zero division errors when taking the log of very small values (several hundred decimals)

Tags: python, zero, divide-by-zero

I am working with very small p-values (several hundred decimals) and I am trying to detect the smallest one in the list. It seems like Python detects many of them as zero so I get a zero division error when I log.

To avoid this, I have written this code:

```
smallest_val = min(np.array(p_value)[np.array(p_value) > 0])
for i in range(len(p_value)):
  if p_value[i] == 0: 
    p_value[i] = smallest_val

p_value_log = []
for i in p_value:
  b = log(i)
  p_value_log.append(b)
```

Of course, this does not solve my problem as several small p-values are then equal to smallest_val and I can't identify the smallest. Any idea on the best way to go about this?

Comment: can't you catch teh exception and provide a quasi-infinte value when it occurs?

Comment: I can catch the exceptions but how do I provide a quasi-infinite value? Sorry if this sounds like a basic question, I am new to Python

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing 0's with `smallest_val`, replace them with `smallest_val/2` or something else between `smallest_val` and 0, so that you can still identify your replacements.

Comment: The problem is that smallest_val is already at the limit of what Python will accept as non-zero so if i divide it by 2, python still thinks the value is zero

Comment: How do you know that?  Your code is finding the smallest non-0 value in the array, not (necessarily) the smallest non-0 possible.

Comment: Because when i use the same code for another data set that varies less widely from the set i'm comparing it to, I manage to plot all the p-values and the smallest one has already several hundred decimals

Comment: So why would one more decimal (which dividing by 2 wouldn't necessarily produce) necessarily go past this limit?